# wxpython PyEmbeddedImage Unicode error?

Tags: python, wxpython

I try to follow some tutorial to embed a image in python (wxpython).
But getting the following error:

```
TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

in the this line:

```
bmp = wx.Image(plane.GetIcon(), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
```

What's wrong with my code?:

```
            plane = PyEmbeddedImage(
            "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAABgVJ"
            "REFUWIXtknlQ1GUYx7+/3WWBXWm5F4RFLh1mNZR1UYMBw1tMCM3RUNHRxswuxtIoGGeiqEkp"
            "J/PWvEJFvIIUFfBsN664N3OJ5VgC2WVPYJe93/5oKrM4KpvxDz///d739zzf7/N9H+AJjyNG"
            "ty2+j6KPiEr0Sc6VRI66IKvQxMu+pb4peL9Q9fLRtpf+i7iTE4Na/lllZeBOiWa4/2gPfrQ2"
            "99rl0kb+2g0LvCoHWg+d0/J3n8imXP6NgdwbmFeoHjOt1z/UY9QGTm3hdeu13CR5WZX55dRZ"
            "2CO68GpZZEfZivcbJoxGNPaVi75UbQ8LAO6re7aaOP4j1tAePjibwa/UGLze1FY1YpEwDANj"
            "nWN7x5nFh5sD0oZrVHuZYpGgAPHE76wV7nOzMwouX5s1GtNDUqoLO3iwrpNktQ6QNImezMyv"
            "JQXGiYerpXO8hqp57yauYbuGOL9dThiLdhNs1xDnfCMZToc+1EUDO/BaKGd1fLg3PVhjJxjj"
            "64Uq2TLBt21zlzA8EtqVNQXND9fklaaFF8cJn43wYoILPUzq+7pJS1aXe0o2Virab6n+WQQA"
            "skTj/D8sbr57VmEkLzWoyPomNVkj0ZGZp2vIBeuUQ8KEg94AwL4cMm1BrXdNYlGXRdKlIF0K"
            "Jcm52/fr9Dt/JrSsKkfSRcv1bSL3dYbx63we1KBGMsHfULJpRjRrz+wl01Aq14NGAXQmE4re"
            "PtiUJpkxIKqvXK6MSg8xIZNPh85OUKYHdl6sG3w6MKxBYTT46Cx2jkpr8Oq+10q9mZy8PjeJ"
            "deS3/n9ZwgfJl3oLFdr2nUU9AWgub8MMLht2AhhNFqjJU7huDwibSpNHSeeasX6cHTUaKz4S"
            "a5Fzpk49OyAm+dQLQc9syr3L9zpwMvw12AK7v8kf32lhHx91ArGvf6liOLtpqu78ELRwbkxF"
            "UmqU8JyexS6V0/BqqBkbeHbUDQIVAwQOUGhuUqL+Up1UWStJJNKPW0dKFxhmCQFgXTHL2CGO"
            "iLEp9dP5KWmSwi7tcgHXhZk3xQx3FkGemkAyCNhBwQoKDA4T3lyW1d+P2xvYNrWxU3/VNpKB"
            "EXdgzsdtE95In7dNcvvsyiWCIPgxCKSaQdTbmLC4jYHcYIXWaPl1GhoNYDqho6ULHCPV8LNI"
            "linetejycP2H3AHVpL1+srAVOyaGKWrdFaKVr8UEw5PmQKcVaIIrCs41ovx0mZ3X3Y04bxeE"
            "uDFBAbAOmhEc4gfXCN/JdIHnpWO9wcfu6WaPG3UCobMoF5/4qxtjJvttjRvv7h/LcwfDZoXO"
            "AbRYGChpMeDM+WrERUdfEV2pyBjr5uA5sW0nZy+exokI9YSK4YLWfjP6TFYwnJnQaAag/6lL"
            "NSjTfmgO/npv1fp91iEN9EzevHRXbvq2YDdTZGIEF2OIDf12gg4TUG1i4sy5RrS3dSsTowSZ"
            "RzaGHwaAD64ajn4iuZeGp8NoLjeqsPgpLYmKj6KcArnoIXT0GC2w0ujolnWDa3etfi5yfsay"
            "UOmNP03NeJFOL8P0PZlFNUSq0hG9TkN6VCrSpFCTMy0aklrURjyWHiFvi+l5OuqPODdu13GC"
            "U3P6w3OLCdacInGbi+9knYdQxnl++ck6Y2lOYbVtr+Q+yZUbyFstAyS1XkXij4odxUS4n8Xb"
            "HPB7AuyUj7Ky05M/WCcIArGYoHZQkPUTiA0MfLVPBLoLTTrV3z+9YIvg6sNPVsGMX7l11apX"
            "pvAjj88MiTmydKnD/tsdc/6ByZp7V1Z/sSt7uYuHc6Azzw+9TFc0tith7lTf/+l2zS7kS72F"
            "7HnFhk9F/aRTrSLlXWqyv62PJBxoIKxF+6zXGAk7tr97nTPUEo2GOx6fu5eoI1aerjeVZJ+v"
            "cByUKknGXQ2ZmVvWQW0t+rGBaXCPbGK54tloBm7fkONmnhiClNhvSZP0nVu7U8r/i/jDnJBG"
            "Tp3zjOfa76vLeYVXWjZRM7IvWJJSpjvdkunR8L3MFukXIor2GXvikxbf4/ZMm+NRiv8dVIl9"
            "fgLNk71QGMHX+Q6QYssPOfX/t+gTnvCEx4pfALyBxD1SVtncAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")


            bmp = wx.Image(plane.GetIcon(), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
            self.button = wx.BitmapButton(Header, -1, bmp, pos=(10, 20), style=wx.NO_BORDER)
```

I also watched around in other tuts but find no solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create a generic Image from a PyEmbeddedImage, you can simply use its GetBitmap method:

```
# plane is your image, f is a Frame
btn = wx.BitmapButton(f, -1, plane.GetBitmap())
```